# Under what permissions/priviledge does the runwithelevatedprivileges code run?

Tags: permissions, security, runwithelevatedprivileges

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges Method Executes the specified method with Full Control rights even if the user does not otherwise have Full Control.

**1)**   But which under which account does this code run?

I read that it runs under the SYSTEM ACCOUNT.

> ```
> a.   what is this system account refers to?
> ```
>
> Is it the account used to create the web application or is it the account used to create the site collection. Or is it the SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM (what is this account, from where did it come?) what?

**2)**   It is said that the code inside this runs under Full Control rights. But then, don't we have to add this particular user (say SYSTEM ACCOUNT?) into any of the groups (member) on our site so that he get the full control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges(v=office.14).aspx

Executes the specified method with Full Control rights even if the user does not otherwise have Full Control.

Parameters
secureCode
Type: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated
A delegate method that is to run with elevated rights. This method runs under the Application Pool identity, which has site collection administrator privileges on all site collections hosted by that application pool.

Comment: So does it also become the system adminsitrator level priviledge?

Comment: What do you mean with System Administrator? Or maybe better: change your question to explain what code do you want to run with Elevated Privileges, so we can understand if it will work with sufficient privileges or not

Comment: Sorry but there is no requirement, just curious to know.. system adminsitrator I meant the Site collection admin (sorry for mistake)

Comment: Yes, it will run as the Application Pool Identity, which will be Site Collection Administrator for every site collection hosted in its Application Pool

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: please check the comment "One Last Point" in the MSDN article mentioned in my answer

Comment: Hey, I came across this link:https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Change-the-Active-Directory-User-Password-Through-SharePoint.aspx Right at the bottom it mentions that "you will need to give the application pool account delegate control permissions to change the users password". So what is the name of the app pool account here: In AD should I go and give permossion to the SHAREPOINT/SYSTEM account or the accountname of apppool given while creating the web application?

Answer (score 1):

It runs under the permissions of the System Account of the WebApplication. The System account is the account with which the App Pool of the Web Application is configured.

Comment: So does it also become the system adminsitrator level priviledge?

Comment: Sorry site collection admin (mistake)

Comment: Yes, the app pool identity has site collection admin rights on all site collections hosted under it. It says so in the linked MSDN article from the other answer ;).

Comment: Hi Vardhaman, System acc. is SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM, but app pool account is the one used when creating the web app: DOMAIN\USERNAME. So for this article: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Change-the-Active-Directory-User-Password-Through-SharePoint.aspx Can you tell me whther I should give permission in AD for SHAREPOINT\SYSTEM or to the DOMAIN\USERNAME ?